# nginx: directly send from location to another named location

Tags: nginx

In my nginx `1.12.2` conf file, I have:

```
upstream app {
  server unix:/tmp/app.sock  fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 443 deferred;

  root /some/dir;

  try_files $uri @app;

  # If the request is for the naked domain, just serve the index bundle
  # without going through Rails
  #
  location = / {
    try_files /index.html =404;
  }

  # If the request if for the /api prefix, go directly to Rails.
  # This location block is not strictly required, but it could be a handy
  # customization hook for extra headers and settings.
  #
  location /api/ {
    # Extra conf!
    try_files @app;
  }

  # The location directory allows very creative configurations.
  # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location
  #
  # This is just a named location to be used in try_files.
  location @app {
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_set_header ...
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }
}
```

There, this is not really right because it has a single argument:

```
  location /api/ {
    # Extra conf!
    try_files @app;
  }
```

...but it communicates well what I'm trying to achieve.
I suppose I could get `try_files` to work by adding a non-esitent file before the last argument.

Is `try_files` the only way to do it, or is there another more idiomatic directive?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to achieve. There is also no @rails_app defined in your config.

Comment: YAGNI. Just get rid of the extra `location`.

Comment: @AlexD thanks for noticing it. Sorry, I was generalizing the config and missed a spot. Now I use `@app` throughout the file.

Comment: @MichaelHampton but what If I want to add extra config for that `/api/` location?

Comment: Then you can `try_files $uri @app;` the same as the rest of the server block.

Comment: Thanks. So, basically there is nothing more "direct" than `try_files`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your scheme will not work. When `nginx` settles on the final `location` block to process the request, it will use the the "settings and headers" that are in scope, which may be inherited from a surrounding block, but **will not** include any "extra headers and settings" from sibling blocks - irrespective of the process taken to find the final `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for more.

If you have common statements applicable to a number of locations, you can offload them to a separate file and include them where necessary. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
}
location /api/ {
    # Extra conf!
    include my/proxy/conf;
}
location @app {
    include my/proxy/conf;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) for more.

Answer (score 43):

We have a pretty complex Nginx configuration and we wanted to use named locations to keep things a bit more **DRY**. Because of this requirement, we had to do exactly what you are trying to.

The sad part is: we couldn't find any direct way of doing it, but the good news is that you can trick Nginx with a `try_files` directive without performance penalties, pointing the first argument to `/dev/null`:

```
try_files /dev/null @the_named_location;
```

It's definitely a workaround and usually I would burn any pull request containing this hack in flames and carefully explain the developer the horrors of not following the standards, etc... but after you get convinced and accept this sad reality, it actually makes your configuration look so much nicer. Really nicer!

We decided that this "hack" is "acceptable" as it proved to bring a big improvement, in terms of code quality in general.

(but it still hurts my eyes sometimes...)

Comment: This is a step up from using `error_page` — thanks! Any ideas how to combine this approach with conditionals (`if`)?

Comment: Unfortunately @intelfx, `try_files` and `if` don't play well together. The main problem is the behavior of `if` is not what most of us would expect (it should be seem more as another location block and **not** as real logical branching). The widely known "If is Evil" blog post (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) helps to understand why. You can always try it and cover your configuration with tons of tests to validate (as you should anyways), but I wouldn't recommend going against the advise of Nginx itself.

Comment: Uh-huh. So that post even lists the `error_page` hack as an _idiom_ for conditional redirection. Oh well. Anyhow — thanks!

Comment: "idiom" with big quotes around it, right? Just a nicer name for a workaround...

Comment: This is awesome. Note that it also works with _variable_ named locations! For example, combining this with `map $http_cookie $upstream` to set `$upstream` to `@named_location` allows you to jump locations based on cookie values.

Comment: This is Nginx falling victim to the [Heptagon of Configuration](https://matt-rickard.com/heptagon-of-configuration/), aka [Configuration Complexity Clock](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2012/05/configuration-complexity-clock.html), where software is doomed to linger perpetually between being "configurable" without being explicitly designed to do so (e.g. through editing of the source code in order to alter behaviour), and being configurable through, say, a configuration file written in some homemade or borrowed domain specific language.

Comment: @VictorSchröder Unfortunally this is not true (I checked this explicitly using `strace`). See my answer for additional details.

Answer (score 15):

Several third-party module directives allows direct jump to named location, e.g. [`ngx.exec`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxexec) from the lua-nginx-module or [`echo_exec`](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module#echo_exec) from the echo-nginx-module (both modules are bundled with the [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/) package). However using the "vanilla" nginx the only way to do it is to use the `try_files` directive trick. Unfortunately the @VictorSchröder [assumption](https://serverfault.com/a/965779/498657) of using `/dev/null` as the `try_files` argument will eliminate the performance penalty due to the system `stat` call is wrong, it is the `/webroot/dev/null` file that will be `stat`'ed in that case. Everyone can check it and see for themselves using the [following](https://echorand.me/posts/strace-nginx/) instruction. So it makes no difference with the commonly used solution like

```
try_files /nonexistent @app;
```

However it is possible to pass an empty sting as the `try_files` parameter:

```
try_files "" @app;
```

This will not eliminate the `stat` system call. However it is the webroot directory that will be `stat`'ed in this case and checked to be an existing physical file on your filesystem, what it most likely isn't (well, at least unless you point your server or location root to such a file, but why would you do such a wild thing?) By my assumption, modern kernels should cache `stat` system call results for the existing filesystem objects more effectively than for non-existing ones. This is only an assumption, so if someone reading this knows better how kernel behaves in this situation, I'll be glad to listen for any clarifications.

I think the last part needs some clarification. Why the `try_files` directive checks the web root to be a physical file and not a directory? That's because the `""` argument is not ended with a slash. An argument ended with a slash makes `try_files` testing it to be a directory, and an argument not ended with a slash makes `try_files` testing it to be a file. That is, the `try_files "/" ...` first check will always succeed (and an explicit or implicit `index` directive will take a job for an index file searching on the next request processing stage, assuming the location has static content handler) if the location root is pointing to the existing directory, and the `try_files "" ...` first check will always fail in that case.

It is also possible that the server webroot would be a non-existent directory, for example when nginx is used for reverse proxying only. Like many other nginx directives the `root` directive, if not being inherited from the previous configuration levels, has a default value of `/html` relative to the nginx prefix. That prefix is specified during the build time and can be checked with the `nginx -V` command (see the `--prefix=...` configure argument). If by example this prefix is equal to `/etc/nginx` (a common case), the default server webroot will be `/etc/nginx/html` which is unlikely to be an existing directory for most environments.

Still I'd prefer `try_files "" ...` rather that `try_files /nonexistent ...`. If by any mean the `nonexistent` file will appear in the webroot directory (think about some kind of defacing hacker attack), the first one will continue to work while the second one will not.

There can be use cases for the `try_files "" ...` construction when the webroot directory is specified using the `alias` directive, especially for the exact or regex matching locations. However I can't see any possible use case for it being placed inside the location using `root` one, so I think nginx development team may consider to update the `try_files` module [source code](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_try_files_module.c) to totally eliminate that extra `stat` call in case of such a usage. It will made possible "unconditional" location jumps without any extra performance penalty at all while keeping compatibility with the any existing configuration.