# Nginx to only load index php

Tags: nginx

I want Nginx to load only index.php on every URL coming in

example.com/urlb?id=1
example.com/urlc?id=2
example.com/urld?id=3
my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
looks as the following -

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name html;



    location ~ \$ {
        try_files /index.php$is_args$args;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix://var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

I want for all the URL above or any URL in the feature to always load index.php

Answer (score 1):

1. Location you used will match only the requests containing `$` symbol, that's definitely not what you want.
2. Using the `try_files` directive you **must** specify at least one file/folder to check. The easiest way to specify the file that would fail the existence check is to specify `dev/null`.

So your location should look like

```
    location / {
        try_files /dev/null /index.php$is_args$args;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix://var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
```

or, without the `try_files` directive

```
    location / {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix://var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
```

Comment: @MichaelHampton No, this check would fail, I already used this solution in my configurations. Found this recipe [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/908086/nginx-directly-send-from-location-to-another-named-location/965779#965779).

Comment: this solution give an error when trying to restart my Nginx **Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**

Comment: this is the code now `server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name html;



     location / {
         try_files /dev/null /index.php$is_args$args;
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix://var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
     }
}`

Comment: @MatCn What `nginx -t` says?

Comment: nginx: [emerg] "try_files" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:5
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: @MatCn I see the extra slash in `fastcgi_pass` directive, try `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;`

Comment: same error **nginx: [emerg] "try_files" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:5
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed**

Comment: @MatCn What is the contents of `/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` file?

Comment: `# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
`

Comment: @MatCn Check the updated answer, both variants shouls work.

Comment: @MatCn Please always add additional information into the question by editing it. The information is difficult to read in comments.

Comment: @IvanShatsky The answer you referred was about a different situation, where people wanted to use only a named location. In this case, there is a physical file `index.php` and error code, which can be implemented with `try_files` like my answer shows.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `location` block instead:

```
location / {
    try_files /index.php$is_args$args =404;

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix://var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}
```

This satisfies the requirement of `try_files` needing at least two arguments. `=404` is the fallback to return `404 Not Found` response when `index.php` does not exist.