# Enabling autoindex conditionally for directories within the Nginx root?

Tags: nginx

Occasionally I need some plain browsable directories on my site. I do achieve this with the following config:

```
  ...
  root /var/www/example.com/file_dump;
  autoindex off;

  ...
  location / {
    try_files $uri /error.html @django;
  }

  location @django {
    ...
  }

  location ~ ^/test/.+/? {
    autoindex on;
  }
```

So if I would create a directory `/var/www/example.com/file_dump/test/something`, I would get the list of files at the address `example.com/test/something`.

I have tried to be smarter than this with the following config:

```
  location / {
    if (!-d test/$uri) {
      autoindex on;
    }
    try_files $uri /error.html @django;
  }
```

But I've met the following error:

> nginx: [emerg] "autoindex" directive is not allowed here...

Why Nginx does not allow `autoindex` within the conditional statements? Can I enable `autoindex` dynamically by the other means?

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you are expecting. What about "nginx does not allow `autoindex` directive within the `if` block in location because **if in location** is not listed as allowed contexts for the [`autoindex`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex) directive (unlike some [others](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root))"? nginx conditional statements is a very special thing and should be used with caution. The best practice is to avoid the `if` whenever possible.

Comment: if is still evil.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I guess my question is more about whether I can employ `autoindex dynamically by the other means`, thus without the `if`. @MichaelHampton Thank you, I'm aware of the [ifisevil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: @NarūnasK Documentation for every nginx directive specifies the context (http, server, location, if in location) where that directive can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Since the enabled/disabled autoindex feature is a `location`-only property, your only way is to use different locations for autoindex-enabled and autoindex-disabled requests. Although some nginx directives allow using the variables as their arguments, `autoindex` is not one of those.

It is completely unclear what do you want to achieve checking the `if (!-d test/$uri) { ... }` statement. If that was meaning *if `$uri` is some existing directory under `/var/www/example.com/file_dump/test/` directory*, here is a possible workaround:

```
server {
    ...
    set $is_dir loc_default;
    if (-d $document_root$uri) { set $is_dir loc_index; }
    set $loc loc_default;
    if ($uri ~ ^/test/.) { set $loc $is_dir; }

    location / {
        try_files /dev/null @$loc;
    }
    location @loc_default {
        try_files $uri /error.html @django;
    }
    location @loc_index {
        autoindex on;
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404 is assumed by default
    }
    location @django {
        ...
    }
}
```

However it is absolutely meaningless to check if the `$uri` is an existing directory, using just

```
    set $loc loc_default;
    if ($uri ~ ^/test/.) { set $loc loc_index; }
```

will give you the same behavior.

Same thing can be achieved using the `map` block:

```
map $uri $loc {
    ~^/test/.    loc_index;
    # you can check multiply patterns here, for example
    ~^/another/  loc_index;
    # if none matched
    default      loc_default;
}
server {
    ...
    location / {
        try_files /dev/null @$loc;
    }
    location @loc_default {
        try_files $uri /error.html @django;
    }
    location @loc_index {
        autoindex on;
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404 is assumed by default
    }
    location @django {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `try_files /dev/null <named_location>` trick is taken from [this](https://serverfault.com/a/965779/498657) excellent answer.